# C# Image Capture Using Webcam , Object Reference Not Set

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, nullreferenceexception, webcam

I want to Capture Image Using Webcam. I am using `WebCam_Capture.dll`library.

sometimes following code work Perfect. (Mostly after `restarting system` or turn on and off `Vcamp.exe`)

sometimes Camera won't turn on and It seems an **Image captured of Green color**

sometimes camera won't turn on and a message-box Shows with description  "`Object reference not set to an instance of an object`" message always on `webcam.Start(0);` in `capture()`

[image]

I want to know the cause of error. How to solve this problem

---

global Variables

```
private WebCamCapture webcam;
private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox _FrameImage;
private int FrameNumber = 50;
bool FCapture=true;
```

Webcam Inetilization

```
 public void InitializeWebCam(ref System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox ImageControl)
    {
        try
        {
            webcam.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        { 
        }
        webcam = new WebCamCapture();
        webcam.FrameNumber = ((ulong)(0ul));
        webcam.TimeToCapture_milliseconds = FrameNumber;
        webcam.ImageCaptured += new WebCamCapture.WebCamEventHandler(webcam_ImageCaptured);
        _FrameImage = ImageControl;
    }
```

Webcam Capturing Function

```
    void webcam_ImageCaptured(object source, WebcamEventArgs e)
    {
        if (FCapture == true)
        {
            imgbox1.Image = e.WebCamImage;
            FCapture = false;
        }
        else
        {
            webcam.Stop();
        }
    }
```

Call function.

```
public void capture()
    {

        InitializeWebCam(ref _FrameImage);
        webcam.TimeToCapture_milliseconds = FrameNumber;
        webcam.Start(0);

    }
```

Comment: And debugger says what? Why do you dispose when starting, considering the variable will be null?

Comment: Debugger won't go further "webcam.Start(0);"
i think that webcam Resource acquired & no releasing by itself  so i use webcam.Dispose();

Comment: Dispose when releasing, you can't dispose null.

Comment: if i  moved it to capture() Function,,, still same error, now it doesn't capture at all, Frequency of Messagbox also increased